# Exception testing in Test Method

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

My actual method is something like :

```
public static string Method(String input ) {
    String Output;
    try {
        Output = StringFunction(Input);
    } catch(Exception e) {}
    return output;
}
```

Test method written so far :

```
public static void testMethod() {
    String testInput = 'SomeString';
    String testOutput ;
    try {
        testOutput = Class.StringFunction(testInput);
    } catch(Exception e) {}
}
```

Currently the exception is not being covered . How can I cover the exception ?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Only way to do this properly is to force error in StringFunction - and unless this is possible you can't cover exception

Comment: @ArturKępczyński- As per client requirements , I need to add both correct value as well as exception.

Comment: Then you either need to find scenario when StringFunction wil lthrow exception or implement mechanism to cause such exception in test (which is stiupid )

Answer (score 3):

I used to do something like the code below in the main Method code

```
if(Test.isRunningTest() && otherTestScenarioCondition) throw new MyException();
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass any incorrect parameter to your **StringFunction** that should do the job for you!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the following:

```
 if(Test.isRunningTest()) {
            DmlException e = new DmlException();
            e.setMessage('This is a constructed exception for testing and code coverage');
            throw e;
        }
```